# Unwanted space in brace expansion

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

I have the following brace expansion (bash shell):

```
echo -e {0..4..2}" "{0..2..2}"\n"
```

I expected this to produce

```
0 0
0 2
2 0
2 2
4 0
4 2
```

but every line of the output except the first has a leading space and there is an extra blank line at the end that I didn't expect. Why is this. Is there a simple way to fix it? Obviously I can do something clunky like pipe to `sed 's/^ //'`, but is there a prettier way without piping to extra commands?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`echo` prints its arguments separated by spaces, even if they include (or generate) newline characters. Additionally it adds one newline character at the end of its output (unless it's `echo -n`).

Use `printf`:

```
printf '%s\n' {0..4..2}" "{0..2..2}
```

When `echo` does something unexpected, always [consider `printf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618). After you get familiar with `printf` it may even become your first choice.

Comment: Even when `echo` *doesn't* do something unexpected, consider using `printf` instead. `echo` can't be unpredictable if it isn't used at all :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting a space that the beginning of each line complicated. The `echo` command spits out its arguments separated by space. Each argument consists of an expansion from `{0..4..2}` and `{0..2..2}` followed by a newline. When you put those two together you see that the space at the beginning of each line is actually the space that `echo` emits between items.

There are a couple of solutions that spring to mind. The first is that if you don't mind having a blank line at the beginning of the output you could put the newline at the start of each expansion,

```
echo -e "\n"{0..4..2}" "{0..2..2}
```

Another is to loop across the arguments and print them separately

```
for seq in {0..4..2}" "{0..2..2}; do echo "$seq"; done
```

or

```
echo -e {0..4..2}"\n"{0..2..2} | xargs printf "%d %d\n"
```

Comment: Note that `echo -e` is quite wildly unreliable. The POSIX standard doesn't allow it to do anything but print `-e` on output, and depending on which runtime flags are active (flags which can be set through environment variables, _or_ at compile time, _or_ through explicit code), bash sometimes will comply with that standard and make `echo -e foo` print `-e foo`. Stephane's excellent answer to [Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) is on-point.

Comment: Yes... I'd have switched it to `printf` but by the time I was ready to hit [Save] I realised that option had already been taken by a different answer. In the end I decided that part of my answer should have minimal changes from the question